# Get list of rows with a second non-blank value and the column header for the second non-blank occurrence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet with data represented as below:

[image]

I need to get all the sites with a second non-blank column in the site's row (except Site, of course) and also get the Column Header value.

In the example, sites B, F and G have a second Y. So the result should be:

[image]

I am not very well versed with Excel Formulas, but I have experimented a bit with INDEX and I can find the second non-blank value itself. But I can't figure out a way to return the result I require.

Using the below formula I get as far as this, but still nowhere near my expected result.

```
{=INDEX(B2:I2,SMALL(IF(B2:I2<>"",COLUMN(B2:I2)-COLUMN(B2)+1),2))}
```

[image]

Edit:

With @Harun24HR 's answer I get this new result.

[image]

Comment: Please include your attempt.

Comment: Like I said, I am not well versed with Excel Formulas. I found the second non-blank using in each row using =INDEX(B2:I2,SMALL(IF(B2:I2<>"",COLUMN(B2:I2)-COLUMN(B2)+1),2)), but that gets me only Y for those rows with a second non-blank value. The value itself is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$I$1,,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$I$11="Y")*($A$2:$A$11=C14)>0,COLUMN($B$2:$I$11),""),2)-1)
```

May need array entry with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

> ***Edit#:*** As per my below screenshot I have used below formulas.

For result column in `J2` cell put

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:I2,"<>")>1,ROW(),"")
```

In `C14` put

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL($J$1:$J$11,ROW(1:1))),"")
```

And in `D14` cell put below formula.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$I$1,MAX(($B$2:$I$11<>"")*($A$2:$A$11=C14)*(COLUMN($B$2:$I$11))))
```

Please note. You no need to array entry for these formulas.

[image]

Comment: How did you get B, F and G in C14:C16?

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping with getting the column header instead of the cell value. I am one step closer. But, the actual requirement is to derive B, F, G dynamically as well.

Comment: Then what is logic to get those values?

Comment: Sites with more than one non-empty column. Basically, filter out any sites with no Dx as Y or only one Dx as Y.

Comment: In result column we can simply use Countifs() formula then have to use aggregate function or some other array function. I am writing from mobile and when I will be on computer, I will do that. With Excel-365 we can do it very easily.

Comment: I don't have Excel-365. I have put your formula in column J and now I have #NUM! for the sites which doesn't meet the criteria and the column header for those that meet. I will try and see if I can research my way to take this new column information and create my result table. Will upvote for helping me overcome the biggest hurdle.

Comment: I could solve it. I will put updated formula.

Comment: @Jayachandran Please cehck my edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236471/discussion-between-jayachandran-and-harun24hr).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up solving this using a combination of the accepted answer (by @Harun24HR) and [How To Extract A Dynamic List From A Data Range Based On A Criteria Without Filters In Excel](https://excel-bytes.com/how-to-extract-a-dynamic-list-from-a-data-range-based-on-a-criteria-without-filters-in-excel/)

In J2 through J11, I added the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$I$1,,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$I$11<>"")*($A$2:$A$11=A2)>0,COLUMN($B$2:$I$11),""),2)-1), "")}
```

In A15 to A24 (same number of rows as the original range), I added the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,SMALL(IF($J$2:$J$11<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$11)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}
```

In B15 to B24, it's a simple VLOOKUP:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A15,$A$2:$J$11,10,0),"")
```

This way, the result table is dynamic.

[image]